# Prove a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $n$ be an odd number and consider the polynomial
$$
X^{n-1}+X^{n-2}+\dots+X+\frac{n-1}{2n-1}
$$
Is it possible to prove that this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

We can consider the polynomial
$$
(n-1)X^{n-1}+(2n-1)X^{n-2}+\dots+(2n-1)X+(2n-1)
$$
whose roots are the reciprocal of the roots of our polynomial. Since gcd$(n-1,2n-1)=1$ I can apply Eisenstein whenever $\exists p$ prime such that $p \mid 2n-1$ and $p^2 \nmid 2n-1$. But what about for example the case $n=5$?. Then
$$
4X^4+9X^3+\dots+9X+9
$$
and I cannot apply Eisenstein to show it's irreducible.

EDIT:(thanks to Sil and Dietrich Burde)

If $2n-1$ is a square and $n$ is prime, we can apply Eisenstein with $p=n$ to the shifted polynomial

$$
(2n-1)(X+1)^{n-1}+(2n-1)(X+1)^{n-2}+ \dots +(2n-1)(X+1)+(n-1)
$$

Since the leading coefficient is $2n-1$, the constant term is $2n(n-1)$ and the $k$-th (with $1 \leq k \leq n-2$) coefficients are $(2n-1){{n}\choose{k+1}}$ which are divisible by $n$ since is prime.

So we are left with the case $n$ is composite and $2n-1$ is a square, i.e. the sequence [A166080](https://oeis.org/A166080).

Comment: Specifically for $n=5$, you can check $4(X+1)^4+\dots+9(X+1)+9=$$4X^4+25X^3+60X^2+70X+40$ which satisfies Eisenstein with $p=5$.

Comment: @Sil Thank you, I edited this for my answer. I tried with $X=Y-1$ instead of $X=Y+1$ before and it didn't work. This  could work indeed for all numbers of the sequence $A001844$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=5$ the polynomial 
$$
9X^4+9X^3+9X^2+9X+4
$$
is irreducible modulo $7$ and hence irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. Replacing $X:=Y+1$ (due to Sil) we obtain
$$
9Y^4 + 45Y^3 + 90Y^2 + 90Y + 40,
$$
which is irreducible by Eisenstein with $p=5$.

The next case is $n=13$, where Eisenstein doesn't work directly for the reciprocal polynomial because $2n-1=5^2$. But then the polynomial  is irreducible over $\Bbb F_{17}$ and $X:=y+1$ gives
$$
25y^{12} + 325y^{11} + 1950y^{10} + 7150y^9 + 17875y^8 + 32175y^7 + 42900y^6 + 42900y^5 + 32175y^4 + 17875y^3 + 7150y^2 + 1950y + 312,
$$
which is Eisenstein with $p=13$. This is probably no coincidence. Shifted Eisenstein should work for many such numbers $n$ from OEIS $A001844$, see the remark.

*Remark:* The sequence of odd numbers $n$ such that $2n-1$ has no prime factor $p$ with $p\mid\mid 2n-1$ is the sequence
[A001844](https://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C13%2C25%2C41&sort=&language=german&go=Suche), starting with
$$
1, 5, 13, 25, 41, 61, 85, 113, 145, 181, 221, 265, 313, 365, 421, 481, 545, 613, 685, 761, 841, 925, \ldots
$$

Comment: It would be great if the shift worked for all those, but it already fails for $n=25$ unfortunately. But it will definitely work whenever $n$ is a prime.

Comment: @Sil the constant term of the shifted polynomial is $2n(n-1)$, so whenever $n$ is not a perfect square, so it is the constant term

Comment: @user289143 Actually for $n=85$ which is not a perfect square it fails as well

Comment: @Sil so we have problems with this sequence, right? [A166080](https://oeis.org/A166080)